# G++ -D option adds digit 1

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I know title is weird, so here is the explanation:

I have some code that I would rather not modify but I need to redefine some functions.
Minimal example is this:

```
int main()
{
strcpy_s(a,b);
}
```

But when I run this:

```
$ g++ -E -P -w -D"strcpy_s(D,S)   strcpy(D,S) buahaha" test.cpp
```

I get:

```
int main()
{
strcpy(a,b) buahaha 1;
}
```

What is this `1`? Ignore buahaha, it is just to show that PP does something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can use the `-D` option:

- `-Dname`
- `-Dname=value`

The first defines `name` as `1`, the second defines `name` as `value`.

`name` is permitted to include parentheses, so that you can define function-like macros on the command line. Something like `-Dfoo bar` contains no equals sign, so it is interpreted as an attempt to define `foo bar` as `1`. Macro names cannot include spaces, so this should probably cause an error message, but it does not get detected, and you end up confusing the compiler. Try `-D"strcpy_s(D,S)=strcpy(D,S) buahaha"` instead.

What I suspect is happening is that `-Dname` is translated to `#define name 1`, and `-Dname=value` is translated to `#define name value`, and error checking only happens after that. This would translate `-D"strcpy_s(D,S) strcpy(D,S) buahaha"` to `#define strcpy_s(D,S) strcpy(D,S) buahaha 1`, and explain the result you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options#index-D-908) shows that the `-D` option has an equals sign in its syntax, which you're not using.

Your command should probably be:

```
$ g++ -E -P -w -D"strcpy_s(D,S)=strcpy(D,S)" test.cpp
```